# Assume $A \times B$ is the smallest set that includes $M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 ; 3xy - 2x - 7y = 2 \}$. What are $A \cap B$ and $A \setminus B$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Now, I've actually solved this already: it's easy enough to see from $y = \frac{2x+2}{3x-7}$ that $|3x-7|\le |2x+2|$ because otherwise the fraction would not be an integer. This returns a set of possible $x$ that you can manually input to find all the viable $(x,y)$ pairs. Finding the two required sets from there is trivial.

However this particular problem is supposed to be solved as part of lessons in combinatorics, and that's where I'm stuck. I can see that without the term $3xy$ I could potentially use combinations with repetition, however I am unsure of how to apply that here.

Comment: I'd solve it essentially like you did ... Though $x=-1$ is also allowed

Comment: Yeh, I forgot to mention the special case of where the numerator equals zero, though I do have it written down in the actual solution.

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

You can write the given equation in the form
$$(3x-7)(3y-2)=20\ .$$
Now do a case analysis. Don't forget negative divisors of $20$.

Comment: While this looks to me like an even cleaner alternative to my own solution (less cases to go through), I admit to be unable to interpret this through combinatorics. In the end, I'm just manually inserting the divisors and seeing which fit for both, eventually giving me the two sets I'm looking for.

It is possible I might have just misinterpreted the actual problem, and solving it in either of these two ways would end up being just fine.